# Vmware workstation power on virtual machine problem

Tags: vmware-workstation

I change the reagin and time setting when my vmware is running, and then I close the vmware restart the computer, "Ditionary problem" is been shown when I power on my ubuntu virtual machine. However I have nothing to do with my vmware workstation, I just change the windows date and region and restart it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YK00.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use compare tool to compare .vmx file and change the config

```
.encoding = "GBK"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "16"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
vvtd.enable = "TRUE"
displayName = "Ubuntu 64 works"
guestOS = "ubuntu-64"
nvram = "Ubuntu 64 λ.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
powerType.powerOff = "soft"
powerType.powerOn = "soft"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
powerType.reset = "soft"
vhv.enable = "TRUE"
vpmc.enable = "TRUE"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
sound.autoDetect = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.present = "TRUE"
numvcpus = "8"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "8"
vcpu.hotadd = "TRUE"
memsize = "8192"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
sata0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "Ubuntu 64 λ.vmdk"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
sata0:1.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
sata0:1.fileName = "auto detect"
sata0:1.present = "TRUE"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci.present = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
svga.graphicsMemoryKB = "786432"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
serial0.fileName = "thinprint"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
extendedConfigFile = "Ubuntu 64 λ.vmxf"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 2d 2f 03 4f 8b 31-bb ab 41 59 d7 bf 6c 82"
uuid.location = "56 4d b7 59 0f 4e a8 56-10 83 f2 c1 bb 2a f4 a2"
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
usb_xhci.pciSlotNumber = "160"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
sata0.pciSlotNumber = "37"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "4194304"
vmotion.checkpointSVGAPrimarySize = "268435456"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:bf:6c:82"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "-675320701"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "43"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"
sata0:1.autodetect = "TRUE"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "1"
toolsInstallManager.lastInstallError = "0"
gui.lastPoweredViewMode = "fullscreen"
gui.stretchGuestMode = "aspect"
gui.enableStretchGuest = "FALSE"
usb_xhci:6.speed = "2"
usb_xhci:6.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:6.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:6.port = "6"
usb_xhci:6.parent = "-1"
usb_xhci:7.speed = "4"
usb_xhci:7.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:7.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:7.port = "7"
usb_xhci:7.parent = "-1"
sata0:1.startConnected = "FALSE"
scsi0:1.deviceType = "rawDisk"
scsi0:1.fileName = "Ubuntu 64 λ-0.vmdk"
scsi0:1.redo = ""
scsi0:1.mode = "independent-persistent"
scsi0:1.present = "TRUE"
workingDir = "Ubuntu 64 λ.vmx.lck"
sata0:0.present = "FALSE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
usb_xhci:4.port = "4"
usb_xhci:4.parent = "-1"
```